# Run node module from powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell

Say that I have a folder with a node module installed inside. How can I, using powershell, run this module ? For example, I have a folder with webpack installed inside and I'd like to be able to do something like

```
node webpack
```

This does not work because it can't find the module. However, it works if I do:

```
node ".\node_module\webpack\bin\webpack.js"
```

However, I can't really use this because I'm working on a powershell script that allows the user to define a json file with actions. For example:

```
{
  "type": "run-node",
  "options": {
    "module": "webpack",
    "parameters": "--configFile=config/webpack.prod.js"
  }
}
```

As the module to execute is dynamic, I don't know where it will be (except if all module are installed in ".\node_modules\module\bin\module.js" ?), so I can't launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `webpack` script in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "node \"./node_module/webpack/bin/webpack.js\""
}
```

Then you can use `npm run webpack` or `yarn webpack` to run it.

Comment: That I don't want to do neither because the script can be launched by specifying a configuration (debug or release) and depending on this, the parameter changes. Basically, I want to keep the file as shown in the question and not having to "pollute" the "package.json" file. I guess that I could open the "package.json" of the module and retrieve the value of the "bin" property but I'm wondering if there is an easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute the command within the node.js script, use the `__dirname` variable.

`__dirname` (almost) always refers to the directory that contains the script.